# MKMapSnapshotter completionHandler never called in parent app when called from WatchKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, mkmapsnapshotter

I have this weird issue: 
I call the parent app with `openParentApplication:reply:` as normal.

It is nicely doing its job getting some data from the internet using async `NSURLRequests` but when I want to get a map image using `MKMapSnapshotter` (still in the parent app) its completion block is never called.

```
MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:options];
[snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"completion handler is called"); //this never called
};
```

I tried to call with: `snapshotter startWithQueue:`on `dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0)` or `dispatch_get_main_queue()` etc. but nothing seems to work.

If I call the same code directly from `WKInterfaceController` or from the parent app  it works just fine.

Comment: Are you opening a background task in `handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:reply:`, as recommended by Apple? Docs here, for reference: https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/tips/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can call/use `MKMapSnapshooter` the way you are wanting to. When you use `openParentApplication` to make the request, it is opening your parent app in background mode and `MKMapSnapshooter` requires Foreground mode to deliver the final image.

as per Apple docs:

> The snapshotter delivers the final image to your app only when it is
>   running in the foreground. The snapshotter must render the final image
>   while your app is in the foreground. If you start generating a
>   snapshot while the app is in the background, or if your app moves to
>   the background while a snapshot is in progress, this behavior delays
>   the delivery of the snapshot until your app returns to the foreground.

Comment: glad I was able to assist