# handleWatchKitExtensionRequest+ asynchronous call

Tags: ios, watchkit

I am trying to use MKMapSnapshotter to take a snapshot from the Map on the containing iPhone app, and then send the image back to the watch. When the containing iPhone app is not running on the background, I cannot get it to work.

This is how I am trying to do:

on AppDelegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void ( ^)( NSDictionary * ))reply {


__block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier watchKitHandler;

watchKitHandler = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]     
beginBackgroundTaskWithName:@"backgroundTask" expirationHandler:^{
  watchKitHandler = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
}];  

NSMutableDictionary *response = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

//========================Building the snapshot===========
CLLocationDegrees latitude = 37.331793f;
CLLocationDegrees longitude = -122.029584f;



MKMapView* mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, (156*2), (108*2))];

mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeHybrid;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
MKCoordinateSpan span = {.latitudeDelta =  0.01, .longitudeDelta =  0.01};
MKCoordinateRegion region = {coord, span};
[mapView setRegion:region];



MKMapSnapshotOptions *options = [[MKMapSnapshotOptions alloc] init];
options.region = mapView.region;
options.size = mapView.frame.size;
options.scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];


MKMapSnapshotter *snapshotter = [[MKMapSnapshotter alloc] initWithOptions:options];

//========================================================
[snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler:^(MKMapSnapshot *snapshot, NSError *error) {
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(snapshot.image);
[response setObject:imageData forKey:@"snapshotimage"];
reply(response);
}];

dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
dispatch_after(dispatch_time( DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)NSEC_PER_SEC * 1),    dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:watchKitHandler];
});
}
```

I am trying different codes suggested by people but I should be doing something wrong in here. Please notice that the "snapshotter startWithCompletionHandler" is done asynchronously.

I have tried the following suggestions but I should be missing something here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30000323/4982919

Any comment and help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check my answer to the same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644997/mkmapsnapshotter-completionhandler-never-called-in-parent-app-when-called-from-w/30653754#30653754

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you know of any alternative?

Comment: If you just need an image of a map you can use `WKInterfaceMap` it actually returns an image.

Comment: I need an image but I need also an animated pin which is not doable on WKInterfaceMap. After trying many approaches, I ended up with a simple approach. Using MapBox Static API. You send lat and long and receive a map image async and then the map image can be used as the background for a group on which you can center an animation.